# Converting the datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using C# & asp.net

```
Textbox values are = "04/03/2010"

Format: mm/dd/yyyy
```

I want to convert the date like this 2010-03-04 instead of 04/03/2010

```
Format: yyyy-mm-dd
```

how to make a code for converting this values....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string newValue = DateTime.ParseExact(oldValue, "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", null)
                          .ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the input value to a date using Date.ParseExact which takes the format as second argument. You'll specify MM/dd/yyyy for that. Then convert the resulting date to your format using ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: This is wrong. "mm" is for minutes. Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

string x = "04/03/2010"

date dte = date.parse(x)

textbox.text = string.format("{0}-{1}-{2}", dte.year,dte.month,dte.day)